# HtmlHelpers in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

As we know that in asp.net mvc if we use

```
@HtmlTextbox("t1",Model.val)
```

then it will create html output as

```
<input type="text" value="Value of val in Model"/>
```

but rather using `htmlhelpers` in asp.net mvc if I directly use

```
<input type="text" value="@Model.val"/>
```

So which is better using `htmlhelpers` or directly html tags in asp.net mvc

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do we use HTML helper in ASP.NET MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681883/why-do-we-use-html-helper-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: No sir this question is different...

Answer (score 1):

I think `<input type="text">` is faster then the `HTML helper` .

but in case of validation I recommend `HTML Helper` it is automatically handle validation if provided in model.

else you need to handle validation in case of `<input type="text">`

Comment: even html support validation

Answer (score 0):

The version that requires least computing (the 2nd one) is faster, but the 1st one is more readable.